# Identify the closest tag for a file version within a git repostiory

Tags: git

I have a repository of files and a file that I know came from it, but I'm not sure at what tag / branch. I know the filename within the repository.

Is there an easy way to search the git tree to find the closest branch/tag the file came from?

EDIT: The full scenario to explain why.

We have a repository of templates. These templates were sometimes used by another program, and when they were used, they were checked out from the main template repository without any git history.

Fast forward to now, we want to be able to programmatically update all of places using these templates, but for many of them, we don't know which version is actually in use, and what updates might have to occur in the rest of the code to allow the update seamlessly. So what we're trying to do is figure out what the closest tag (a-la git describe) would be for a particular version of a particular template. From there, we can arrange the rest of the updates as needed.

So I have a copy of a template, I know it came from my repo, but I don't know when it came from.

Comment: `git log --reverse the-filename`?

Comment: That gives me the log for commits that change the file, but what I'd like is for it to look at the MD5 and find when that MD5 first appeared for that filename. I suppose I could loop through git-log for the file and check the MD5 for the file at each commit and see when it appears. That wouldn't catch unmerged branches though.

Comment: You want to… search for a file by its MD5 hash? You’re not mixing this up with Git’s SHA-1 commit ids? You’ll also have to explain what “closest branch/tag” means…

Comment: Yes, sorry, SHA-1. But really, the hash function in question isn't really relevant. I want to search for a file by the file's content, and know the most recent branch / tag of the repository that version of the file appears in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have some content, and you want to find at what point in history that content appeared at a given path in the repo.

You mention something about MD5; perhaps you meant the hash used by git (which is actually a SHA1), but even if you didn't git's hash is what to use.  Note that you can't use just any utility to calculate the SHA1 because git attaches a header to the content and also may apply some filters before calculating the hash.  So:

```
git hash-object file-containing-the-target-content
```

and make note of the SHA1 it gives you.

Next you need log output that includes the sha1 of the file.  One way would be

```
git log --raw --no-abbrev --all --full-history --reverse -- path/to/file/in/repo
```

and search the output for the first occurrence of the sha1 value you found above.  (There may be a way to automate the search of the content; I'm thinking about that one but for some reason it's not clicking.  But just capturing the log or piping it to less, then searching for the sha1 value, would work without too much trouble.)

And maybe that's exactly what you need to do... but to be honest I can't think of what the application for this technique would be.  If you're wanting to know when a particular bit of content got into the repo, playing with `git blame` might prove more fruitful.

Comment: A variation on this... because you said something in comments about unmerged branches, it makes me think you might have to deal with whether the content was introduced more than 1 time.  With the above log output, each entry will list a "before SHA1" followed by an "after SHA1", so you could go ahead and look for every line where the 2nd SHA1 matches your target content.  Each commit containing such a record is a commit that introduced that content.

Comment: You can pipe the `git log` output through `| (export HL=$(echo -e '\033[41m\033[37m'); export EL=$(echo -e '\033[0m'); sed "s/<hash-object>/${HL}\0${EL}/g")`; if you want to preserve the log colorization you'll want to add `--color=always` to `git log`.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I added some extra details in the question to give context to what I'm looking for and why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this separately because @mark-adelsberger got me most of the way there, but didn't quite get it in one shot. Here's how to locate the commit of a file from it's content, and get the closest tag:

```
hash=$(git hash-object file_of_unknown_origin)
commit_hash=$(git log --raw --no-abbrev --all --full-history --reverse --format=format:%H -- path/to/file | sed 's/^:[0-9]* [0-9]* [a-z0-9]* //' | grep -B1 $hash | head -n 1)
git checkout $commit_hash
git describe --tags
```